# Incompatible types : Object cant not be converted to String in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to use object Array in my project and i get an error :

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
```

on this line :

```
ST1 = new String[]{emt1, emt2, emt3, emt4};
```

Now i don't figure out what is the cause of this error . please help me .

```
Object[] ST1;
Object emt1,emt2,emt3,emt4;


private void jButton3ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        emt1 = null;
        emt2 = null;
        emt3 = null;
        emt4 = null;
        ST1 = new String[]{emt1, emt2, emt3, emt4};
    }
      ....
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you exactly try to do, because I don't understand the concept of your program.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `new Object[]{...}`?

Comment: Why declare four `Object` variables and try and put them in a `String` array?

Comment: `new String[]{emt1, emt2, emt3, emt4}` this is a `String` Array, create an Object Array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two way one is to cast every Object emt1, emt2, .. to String like this :

```
ST1 = new String[]{(String)emt1, (String)emt2, (String)emt3, (String)emt4};
```

Or you should to change the type of your attribute:

```
Object emt1, emt2, emt3, emt4;
```

To String

```
String emt1, emt2, emt3, emt4;
ST1 = new String[]{emt1, emt2, emt3, emt4};
```

Comment: Thanks @YCF_L. your answer worked for me  too and is very clear than the one of  anacon at the top

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `emt1,emt2,emt3,emt4` as `Object`. In the last line where you are creating the assigning the array to the variable `ST1`, you are creating a `String` array and storing `Object` intances in it. This is what is causing the problem.

If you wish to use the objects in this manner and if you are sure that the `emt1,emt2,emt3,emt4` objects are all strings, you can add a cast to your code like this:

```
    ST1 = new String[] { (String) emt1, (String) emt2, (String) emt3, (String) emt4 };
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

A String is an Object, but an Object is not necessarily a String.

You try to use variables which are Objects where the compiler expects Strings, and the compiler tells you so.  Perhaps the emt1, emt2, emt3 and emt4 variables should have been declared as String?  (Hard to tell from the snippet given).